# Have the save button show only for the current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to get the save button to show up on the current row that I press the save button on. Currently, it works fine except if I have the same product but didn't options for the product.

I have tried:

```
$(this).parent('tr');
```

but it doesn't help either

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <tr class="product-1" prod-id="1" qty="1">
    <form action="#" class="edit-cart-form"></form>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Test Product</td>
    <td>$20.00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="add-qty">
        <i class="fa fa-minus minus-qty"></i>
        <input type="text" value="1" />
        <i class="fa fa-plus plus-qty"></i>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">save</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product-1" prod-id="2" qty="1">
    <form action="#" class="edit-cart-form"></form>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Test Product</td>
    <td>$20.00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="add-qty">
        <i class="fa fa-minus minus-qty"></i>
        <input type="text" value="1" />
        <i class="fa fa-plus plus-qty"></i>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">save</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.plus-qty').click(function() {
  var target = '.product-' + $(this).closest('tr').attr('prod-id') + ' .save';
  $(target).show();
});

$('.minus-qty').click(function() {
  var target = '.product-1' + $(this).closest('tr').attr('prod-id') + ' .save';
  $(target).show();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x25u11v7/)**

Comment: `var target = $(this).parent().find("a.save");` should do the trick.

Comment: Please don't be like Angular. **Use valid attributes** like `data-prod-id="1"` and `data-qty="1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your target string was over-complicating it, which is the cause of your problem.

The following lines do what you intend i believe

```
$('.plus-qty, .minus-qty').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.save').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you almost got it right by using `parent` but didn't succeed. Here is working example.
Use `data` attributes. You can then easily get their values using [data](https://api.jquery.com/data) method.

```
var target = $(this).parent().find("a.save");
```

```js
$('.plus-qty, .minus-qty').click(function() {
  $($(this).parent().find("a.save")).show();
});
```

```css
.save {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <tr class="product-1" data-prod-id="1" data-qty="1">
    <form action="#" class="edit-cart-form"></form>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Test Product</td>
    <td>$20.00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="add-qty">
        <i class="fa fa-minus minus-qty"></i>
        <input type="text" value="1" />
        <i class="fa fa-plus plus-qty"></i>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">save</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product-1" data-prod-id="2" data-qty="1">
    <form action="#" class="edit-cart-form"></form>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Test Product</td>
    <td>$20.00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="add-qty">
        <i class="fa fa-minus minus-qty"></i>
        <input type="text" value="1" />
        <i class="fa fa-plus plus-qty"></i>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">save</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why wrapping again `target` into a jQuery Object? Also don't you find your code a bit repetitive?

Answer (score 0):

Use Selector `$(this).closest('tr').find('.save');`

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/x25u11v7/4/